# Textbox stack Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, stack, textarea

I'm trying to do a Text-area witch stack data from other text-box, in "AngularJs". Does anybody have any idea how this might be done?
This will be similar to the text-box we have on StackOverflow to add Tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited**

See working example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/XQkuJIOREuHiV4EuZ2wX?p=preview

Tags? take a look at Select2: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#tags

Comment: You could use [AngularUI](http://angular-ui.github.io/#/directives-select2) that already wraps Select2 in Angular way.